# What is wrong with my form via Ajax to PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Been scouring this site and find many AJAX to PHP examples but following these I cannot figure why on earth my scripts are not working.

I have an HTML form with a button. You click the button it calls a Bootstrap modal window. You enter an email address click Submit.

It posts to a PHP file that will email me.

The reason I am implementing using AJAX is because I do not want the ACTION and METHOD submit on the form. I want to submit via AJAX so the user is not redirected to my PHP page.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
       <title>test</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button#submit").click(function(){            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "email.php", // 
                data: $('form.icontact').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#thanks").html(msg)
                    $("#contact").modal('hide');    
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
 </head>
 <body>          
        <div class="container"> <!-- numbers cannot total more than 12 for rows-->
        <div id="thanks"><p><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Submit!</a></p></div>            

        </div>

        <!--contact modal-->
        <div class="modal fade"id="contact" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form class ="form-horizontal" name="icontact" id="icontact">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                          <h4>testemail</h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                       <p>Please enter your email address and click submit to receive     your free first chapter</p>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email: </label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                               <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fromaddress" placeholder="new@example.com" name="fromaddress" />
                               <input type="hidden" id ="subject" value="enter in your email" name="subject" />
                            </div>
                         </div>

                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>


                       </div>
                   </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 </body>
```

and here is the php file. I get failure when I run it and it is passing the data in the URL like a GET. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

function spamcheck($field) {
  // Sanitize e-mail address
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
  // Validate e-mail address
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

if (isset($_POST["fromaddress"])) {
    // Check if "from" email address is valid
    $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["fromaddress"]);
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
     echo "Invalid input";
    } else {
      echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks!</span><br><br>";

  $from = strip_tags($_POST["fromaddress"]); // sender
  $subject = strip_tags($_POST["subject"]);
  $message = "Thanks.";
  // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
  $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
  // send mail
  mail("test@test.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");

    }
  }


?>
```

Comment: `$('form.icontact').serialize()` should be `$('#icontact').serialize()` for a start

Comment: `$("button#submit").click(` you should not rely on the user clicking a button to submit the form - that is not the only way that the form can be submitted. Always listen for the submit `$('#icontact').submit(function(){})`

Comment: Another thing - you've put your javascript includes where they belong but the procedural script in `<head>` for some reason. It belongs after the includes before `</body>`.

Comment: Thanks to all of these comments they fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you form is submitting either ways. You haven't prevented the default behaviour of the submit button. i.e. Submitting the form and redirecting to the form-action.

Do something like this

```
$("button#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // This line avoids the default submit event.

    //Rest of stuff as you have it.....
});
```

A better option is to do the AJAX call on the `.submit()` rather than on the `.click()` as below

```
$("form#icontact").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Proceed with other stuff as is...

});
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: They always forget the e.preventDefault(); :)